# Focal Statistics produces corrupted/ partial Output ArcMap 10.4.1

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcgis-10.4, focal-statistics

I recently encountered an issue with ArcMap that I am not able to solve by a workaround:

I have a grid file covering the EU plus a couple of other countries inside a *.gdp (cell size 1000 x 1000 m). The file contains a population grid, meaning different values for all cells where population is situated but in areas where nobody lives, I have 0 values resulting in around 7.1 million individual cells.

I need to use the tool 'Focal Statistics' in order to calculate the population potential within a given area around each point.

Everytime I try, I receive a corrupted output (please see image attached). It does not only produce a partial output but reutrns wrong values (negative values).
I already tried to change the environmental settings (m to map units, etc.) it did not work.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found a simple workaround;

converting the raster layer into a point feature layer and then running the tool 'Point Statistics' with the same parameters has helped.